# Setup a cloned react-native project created via react-native init command

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have created a react-native project XYZApp using `react-native init` which is pushed in GitHub repo.

Now when I am cloning the project on a different system. following is the directory structure

app/XYZApp

Following is the set of commands and steps I am using.

```
cd app

brew install node

brew install watchman
```

#

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

#

```
install android studio and required SDKs
```

#

```
install X-Code
```

## #

```
react-native init MyApp 

prompt: Directory MyApp already exists. Continue?:  (no) 

I am typing - yes

npm install [all dependencies]

react-native link
```

Through all the above steps, some new default files are getting created which runs a default app, with some minor changes in those files I am able to run the app. But I know this is not the correct way of doing this.

I tried several other methods also,
like `npm start`

I checked several links but could not find the correct method for the setup after cloning.
Most of them are mentioned for `create-react-native-app` method.

It will be great if someone can help me regarding this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after cloning
Don't do this

```
react-native init MyApp 

prompt: Directory MyApp already exists. Continue?:  (no) 

I am typing - yes

npm install [all dependencies]

react-native link
```

just go to cloned app directory XYZApp and do

```
npm install
```

and all set to run the app using

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: Some repositories doesn't include those android and ios folders. How do you  include those in the project?

Comment: Are you talking about npm packages?

Comment: No, those at the root folder when you create a new react-native project. What I know how to do this is create a new project, then just add the files from the repo especially package.json then run npm install.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2019 **React Native 0.60.0+**:

First you need to install all the node modules by running

```
npm install
```

If you're using libraries with native dependencies like [react-native-gesture-handler](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler) these libraries need to be linked correctly. To do so run

```
react-native link
```

For setting up the iOS project correctly you need to install the CocoaPods dependencies:

```
cd ios && pod install
```